# image not found while webrtc framework implement

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I am implement demo of WebRTC but i am referring below example for WebRTC i am getting error like below

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C9A9D890-946F-4045-9FB3-C1F05912F4E2/webrtc-socketio-ios.app/Frameworks/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO
  Reason: image not found
```

**Referral Link of Demo**

https://github.com/digixtechnology/iOSRTC

i tried many solution with my research like below

1. Add framework in Embedded Binaries
2. Delete Derived Data
3. Change Run Path To `$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks`

but still i am getting crash and error Image Not Found so please some one help me to solve this

Answer (score 2):

1. **Comment** **use_frameworks**! line in pod file, reinstall the libraries and it **works**.
2. Also check the paths of the frameworks included in your application under

   **Build Settings --> Search Paths --> Framework Search Paths**

**NOTE**: **Make sure to delete your build and then install again**

Answer (score 1):

## Swift Package Manager Solution

In my case, I've added WebRTC via **[Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/)**. And I've got the same exact error.

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC.git", from: "93.0.0")
```

**But**, I've forgot to add under target dependencies. Here is my solution:

```
target(
    name: "MyClientName",
    dependencies: ["SomeOtherDependency", "**WebRTC**"]),
```

Best